# Integral of form pulled back from torus to sphere is zero

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I'm trying to show that when we pull back (with any map $f: S^2 \to T^2$  any 2-form on the 2-torus to the 2-sphere it's integral is zero.

I understand we can choose coordinates $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ for $T^2$ and then any 2-form can be written as a multiple of $\omega = d\theta_1 \wedge d\theta_2$. I'm trying to show:

$$\int_{S^2} f^*(d\theta_1 \wedge d\theta_2) = 0$$

Now I'm trying to use the fact that every closed 1-form on $S^2$ is exact, however that seems to be obvious here anyway as $f^*(d\theta_1) = d(\theta_1 f)$ so I'm now trying to show that the integral of $d(\theta_1 f) \wedge d(\theta_1 f)$ is zero but I am struggling to proceed.

Comment: Your "seems to be obvious" is flawed: $\theta_1$ is *not* a globally defined continuous (let alone smooth) function. So you really *do* need to use the fact that closed $1$-forms on the sphere are exact. The wedge product of a closed $1$-form and an exact $1$-form is still exact. And the integral of an exact $2$-form on a compact oriented surface *without boundary* is always $0$. Why?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So the form $f^*(d\theta_1)$ is only exact on some open set (where $\theta_1$ does not become "multi-valued")? From your second remark then we can deduce $f^*(d\theta_1) \wedge f^*(d\theta_1)$ is exact and then the result follows from Stokes' theorem?

Comment: Your remark about $\theta_1$ not being globally smooth has now made me question how we know that $f^*(d\theta_1)$ is exact. Before I was saying that $d f^*(d \theta_1) = f^*(d^2 \theta_1) = 0$ but does that hold globally?

Comment: Very simple: $d\theta$ is a globally-defined $1$-form on the circle, even though $\theta$ is not a globally-defined function. Work this out carefully. (If you've studied complex variables, you've seen the same phenomenon with log being multivalued.)

Comment: Okay great, thanks for your help. This is just a consequence of $d(\theta+\pi) = d\theta$ so it is well-defined if we change charts?

Comment: Right. Or you can write it in cartesian coordinates as $$d\theta = \frac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}.$$ Perhaps this looks familiar. :)

Comment: The restriction of that form to $S^1$ as an embedded sub manifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes, sure. In fact, the restriction to a circle of *any* radius centered at the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $\pi \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{T}^2$ the universal cover map. Since $S^2$ is simply connected, the map $f \colon S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{T}^2$ factors through $\pi$ and we can find a smooth $g \colon S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f = \pi \circ g$. If $\omega$ is a two-form on $\mathbb{T}^2$, then we have

$$ \int_{S^2} f^{*}(\omega) = \int_{S^2} (\pi \circ g)^{*}(\omega) = \int_{S^2} g^{*}(\pi^{*}(\omega)).$$

The form $\pi^{*}(\omega)$ is a two-form on $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence exact and so $g^{*}(\pi^{*}(\omega))$ is also exact and the integral is zero by Stoke's theorem.

Comment: These seems like a good solution however I haven't covered universal covers yet (after reading up it doesn't seem to hard) but out of interest do you think there is a way to do this without using a universal cover map?

Comment: Well, $f^{*}(d \theta_1 \wedge d \theta_2) = f^{*}(d \theta_1) \wedge f^{*}(d \theta_2)$ is the wedge of two exact 1-forms on $S^2$ so it is exact and the integral is zero but a general two-form on $\mathbb{T}^2$ is of the form $g d\theta_1 \wedge d\theta_2$ where $g \colon \mathbb{T}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and the previous argument doesn't go through as neatly. I'm not sure how to handle $g$ other than moving to the universal cover.